# How to order by dates with time periods with current date first then future time periods and then past time periods?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-order-by

I have a table with columns ID, START_DATE and END_DATE. What I want to do is to execute a query which orders the resulting rows in the following order:

If the current date is 2020-12-14 then the result should be

```
START_DATE  END_DATE
2020-12-8   2020-12-18     -----> Time periods which contains current day and are ordered by start_date in ASCENDING order.
2020-12-9   2020-12-15     
2020-12-10  2020-12-17     
2020-12-15  2020-12-17     -----> Time periods with START DATE > current date and are ordered by start_date in ASCENDING order.
2020-12-16  2020-12-22
2020-12-21  2020-12-25
2020-12-9   2020-12-13     ----->Time periods with END DATE < current date and are ordered by start_date in DESCENDING order.
2020-12-6   2020-12-8
2020-12-1   2020-12-9
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: When you demonstrate an example data for MySQL, use `YYYY-MM-DD` date format always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need in something similar to

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
              THEN 1
              WHEN start_date > CURRENT_DATE
              THEN 2
              ELSE 3 END,
         CASE WHEN end_date > CURRENT_DATE
              THEN start_date + 0
              ELSE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, start_date)
              END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b5df93638176fcf288f52faa741ad70)

`start_date + 0` needed for to convert the result of this CASE to numeric. Without it the CASE alternatives combines date and numeric values which causes the final datatype to be a string - with wrong sorting order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `conditional ordering` as follows:

```
Select * from your_table
Order by 
  case when CURRENT_DATE between start_date and end_date OR start_date > CURRENT_DATE 
       then 1
       When end_date < CURRENT_DATE 
       then 2 
  end,
  case when CURRENT_DATE between start_date and end_date or start_date > CURRENT_DATE 
       then date_diff(start_date, CURRENT_DATE) 
       When end_date < CURRENT_DATE 
       then date_diff(CURRENT_DATE,start_date) 
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, I would write this as:

```
order by (curdate() between start_date and end_date) desc,
         (curdate() > curdate()) desc
```

`case` expressions are not needed because MySQL treats boolean values as a number, with `1` for true and `0` for false.